# How to add a field from another list into sharepoint designer workflow2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

**UPDATED**: Thank you Teylyn for pointing out I referred to InfoPath as opposed to SharePoint.

I am working on a work path I had inherited.
I was asked to include a field from another list ( I'm assuming it's from another list because it does not show up in the current item drop-down ).
Could the field be hidden somehow because I have seen the field associated with the same current list items on another view ).
If it is hidden , how can show it?
If it is indeed an item from another list, how do I make it accessible to the the current workflow. Thank you!

UPDATE: I had found that the second list has both fields I need and are relative. Item PO and Item PR. Now how do I get item PR into the previous list and associate it to the PO of the current item? I'm not sure how to query that using SharePoint 2010 workflow.

Comment: You don't need to assume. Just ask the people who tasked you to include the field. They should be able to tell you where you can find it. You also seem to be confusing SharePoint Designer and InfoPath. InfoPath does not have a drop down with Current Item. InfoPath does not do workflows (unless you know a few tricks). That's SPD. Maybe you need to straighten out what tool you are using and then try to figure out what you are supposed to achieve. Once you have figured that out, explain the business logic if you need more help.

Comment: Ouch! Mea Culpa.. Yes my mistake - running on minimal sleep.  SharePoint Designer 2010 - using a workflow - current item dropdown  does not show the field I saw associated with it a very similar area. Granted more access, I see that whoever created the data input created a duplication of entries. I had found that the second list has both fields I need and are relative. Item PO and Item PR. Now how do I get item PR into the previous list and associate it to the PO of the current item.

Comment: How about a little love today teylyn?  Those "people" to ask are gone and I am left to make heads and tails of it. So I indeed assumed. Here's a hug.

Comment: This is a big muddle. I suggest you edit your post and start over. What are you trying to achieve? What is the input? What is the desired output? What is the business logic in plain words? If two lists are involved, share some details about the list fields and what the workflow is supposed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a list form or a form deployed in a forms library? If it's a form deployed to a forms library, check the data connection, maybe the author for the form missed checking that field and retrieving it in the data connection.

You can also open the lists directly and check in which list/library the field exists, if it's in another library, you can query that library through a data connection as well, and get that field's value through a condition depending on the current item's values. For example, if you have List1, and List2, and you're developing the form on List1, you can query List2 for your target field depending on a condition for List1 item that you are on, because when you query a list it will retrieve a collection of items, and you need a condition to get only one item, once you do that you can store it in your form and use it in a workflow.

**Update**

If you need to only get the field in your workflow, without the need to use it in your form as you've stated in your update, then you can do so inside the workflow itself. In the workflow you can define a variable, and set this variable to do the value of a lookup, and choose the other list from the lookup dialog, then choose the field that you want, for example, in the lookup dialog you'll choose List1 as the data source, and choose column1 as the field. At the bottom you will see 2 sections, these represent the condition, to specify which item exactly that you need to lookup. Remember you are looking up a column1 of the list, but the list has many items and you need only 1 item to get. So at the bottom you specify the condition, for example, choose ID, and in the last field you'll enter the value of that ID OR you can get column1 for the item that has the ID of the current item.

It all happens in that lookup dialog, you should spend a bit of time checking it and you'll figure it out. When you get the data, you can easily set value of current item. Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: Thank you Mohammed for the generosity. Would you know how I can apply to the comment above using SharePoint Designer 2010. Again I apologize for the mistake. It's not a usual occurrence.

Comment: Hi Mike, you need to do so in InfoPath, you won't be using SharePoint designer in this. You get data connection in InfoPath, and get the item in a specific condition. Meaning that there must be something on the form that you can associate with the item you want to retrieve using a condition. Remember all in InfoPath. Once you get the item, you can access the field and store it in a field local in the form, and publish it with the form, then use SharePoint designer workflow to read it at the end.

Comment: Hello Mohamed, sorry some of this is new to me. Would you please be able to give me an example. Let's say I am trying to copy the field LL1 from list 1 to list 2 into a field with the same name LL2. I'm not sure what commands to use. Thank you again.

Comment: This question does not seem to be about InfoPath at all. I think your answer is confusing the OP even more. The OP is working with a SharePoint Designer workflow and apparently needs to reference a field in another list. Throwing in concepts like forms libraries and data connection will totally send them on the garden path.

Comment: @teylyn My answer is based on his original post when he said "he has a form and was asked to include a field from another list". Then you asked him to modify his question, and then you tell me my answer is irrelevant to the updated question? You could just advice me to modify my answer for the new updated question and that's it!

Comment: Hi Mike, check my updated answer.